# ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED gives Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android

I create a static Handler to change some UI texts and plots in an activity. There is a timer created in a bluetooth service. Every second it will check the database for last message and update the time. For example, message comes in 1 second ago 2 seconds ago 3 seconds ago... I store the time when last message came in as yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss a java Date long value.

My problem is at a line where "if (HomeActivity.mHandler != null) {" in the service class below, it gives an error "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". This happens when I shut down and restart the phone. The ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED is catch and trying to run that code, then it throws exception. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Here is my codes:

Activity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

   public static Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
         super.handleMessage(msg);

         final Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
          ...
         }
      };

}
```

Service:

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {

      // doing some other bluetooth stuffs here
      ...

      int ONE_SECOND = 1*1000;
      Timer updateTimer = new Timer();
      updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            try {
            if (HomeActivity.mHandler != null) { // error
               final Message msg = HomeActivity.mHandler.obtainMessage();
               Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

               bundle.putString("input", "update");
               msg.setData(bundle);

               HomeActivity.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

    }, 0, ONE_SECOND);
}
```

Broadcast:

```
public class BluetoothBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      final String action = intent.getAction();

      if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
         Intent i = new Intent(context, BluetoothLeService.class);
         context.startService(i);
      }
   }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<!-- Start the service when phone is boot. -->
<receiver android:name="com.example.BluetoothBroadcast" >
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably should be closer to this:

```
private void createHandler() { 
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
      public void run() { 
           Looper.prepare();

           final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override 
                public void run() { 
                   // Do Work 
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    Looper.myLooper().quit();
               } 
            }, 2000); 

            Looper.loop();
        } 
    }; 
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for your answer. So I guess I need to use my HomeActivity.mHandler inside a UI thread? I am creating the handler as static variable and in the Activity class to change the UI components. So I am not sure how exactly I can transfer your technique into my solution. Please advise thanks!!!

Comment: Considering that the ultimate purpose is to update this UI, this is probably not the proper solution, if it would even work at all.

Comment: In the code that I provide, it works if you simply run the app. It just crash when the phone reboots.

Comment: Looper.prepare() needed at top of your run block..such a simple thing even the error message pointed to it

Comment: @Fred Grott yes, you are right... sorry for being stupid... it fixes it

Comment: That is okay, we all overlook something once in awhile :)